# Length of the data to decrypt is invalid Message when decrypt AES by C#

Tags: c#, aes

I have two buttons use AES algorithm one for encryption and another one for decryption .when I apply encryption is fine but when I apply decryption I face this message error.

I am using `Convert.FromBase64String(s)` but it still does not work.

```
  private void Encryption_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
            save.FileName = "DefaultOutputName.txt"
            save.Filter = "Text File | *.txt";

            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            {

                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(save.OpenFile());

                cipherdata = textBox2.Text;

                plainbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cipherdata);
                plainkey= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0123456789abcdef");
                desobj.Key = plainkey;
                desobj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                desobj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, desobj.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cs.Write(plainbytes, 0, plainbytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
                cipherbytes = ms.ToArray();
                Convert.ToBase64String(cipherbytes);
                MessageBox.Show(cipherbytes.Length.ToString());
                ms.Close();
                writer.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(cipherbytes));

                writer.Dispose();

                writer.Close();

            }
        }

        private void decryption_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string s = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);

                cipherbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s); 
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms1 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(cipherbytes);
                CryptoStream cs1 = new CryptoStream(ms1, desobj.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                cs1.Read(cipherbytes, 0, cipherbytes.Length);
                plainbytes2 = ms1.ToArray();

                cs1.Close();
                ms1.Close();
                textBox2.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plainbytes2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: You should check the output file to see if it has any data written to it.  You should also be disposing those `IDisposable` objects

Comment: yes i check file that saves encrypted text and its work

Comment: You must FlushFinalBlock() of the CryptoStream before you close it. Also try to use the _Using { }_ block to make sure that the streams are closed then disposed, and not being disposed then closed. Good luck.